# HTML5 canvas animation of line

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

I am trying to animate a line in HTML5 canvas. The line is supposed to move according to the keyboard strokes (just as the red square). Unfortunately it gets longer but it should just move sideways...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="400">Your browser does not support the canvas tag.</canvas>
<script>
 var canvas;
 var ctx;
 var incrementX = 0;
 var x = 250; 
 var y = 350; 

function init() {
// This function is called after the page is loaded

// 1 - Get the canvas
canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');

// 2 - Get the context
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');



// 3 add key listeners to the window element
window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeydown, false);
window.addEventListener('keyup', handleKeyup, false);
// 4 - start the animation
requestId = requestAnimationFrame(animationLoop);
}

function handleKeydown(evt) {

if (evt.keyCode === 37) {
   //left key
   incrementX = -1;
} else if (evt.keyCode === 39) {
   // right key
   incrementX = 1;
}
}

function handleKeyup(evt) {
incrementX = 0;
}

function animationLoop() {
// 1 - Clear
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

// 2 Draw
drawLine(x, y);

// 3 Move
x += incrementX;

// call again mainloop after 16.6 ms (60 frames/s)
requestId = requestAnimationFrame(animationLoop);
}




function drawLine(x, y) {

ctx.save();

ctx.translate(x, y);

ctx.moveTo(0,0);
ctx.lineTo(100,0);
ctx.stroke();


ctx.fillStyle='red';
 ctx.fillRect(35,30,20,20);

ctx.restore();
}






</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have not begun a stroke so each time you call drawLine you just add to the existing one. Add `ctx.beginPath()` before the `ctx.moveTo` function in `drawLine`

Comment: works perfectly. thanks a lot.